# Javascript regex split reject null

Tags: javascript, regex, null, split

Is it possible to make a JavaScript regex reject null matches?

Can the String.split() method be told to reject null values?

```
console.log("abcccab".split("c"));
//result: ["ab", "", "", "ab"]
//desired result: ["ab", "ab"]
```

-

While I was testing this I came across a partial answer on accident:

```
console.log("abccacaab".split(/c+/));
//returns: ["ab", "a", "aab"]
```

But, a problem arises when the match is at the start:

```
console.log("abccacaab".split(/a+/));
//returns: ["", "bcc", "c", "b"]
//          ^^
```

Is there a clean answer? Or do we just have to deal with it?

Comment: How about matching all sequences of characters except `c`?

Comment: @nathanhayfield That's what I'm wanting to avoid

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This isn't precisely a regex solution, but a filter would make quick work of it.

```
"abcccab".split("c").filter(Boolean);
```

This will filter out the falsey `""` values.

Comment: I feel like I've been stealing all your rep! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888689/remove-empty-strings-from-array-while-keeping-record-without-loop/19888749#19888749

Comment: @Isaac: LOL, nah I make my answers into CW's anyway. Glad to see you use the info!

Answer (score 1):

Trim the matches from the ends of the string before you split:

```
console.log("abccacaab".replace(/^a+|a+$/g, '').split(/a+/));

// ["bcc", "c", "b"]
```

Comment: That's nice, not as clean as squint's answer though

Comment: @Nope, I left it here because you told nathanhayfield that you wanted to avoiding iterating through the array and removing the empty strings, which is what filter does.