# Remove empty strings from array while keeping record Without Loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, string, removeall

This question was asked here:
[Remove empty strings from array while keeping record of indexes with non empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113243/remove-empty-strings-from-array-while-keeping-record-of-indexes-with-non-empty-s)

If you'd notice the given as @Baz layed it out;

```
"I", "am", "", "still", "here", "", "man"
```

*"and from this I wish to produce the following two arrays:"*

```
"I", "am", "still", "here", "man"
```

All the *Answers* to this question referred to a form of looping.

My question: Is there a possibility to **remove** all `index`es with `empty` `string` **without any looping?** ... is there any other alternative apart from iterating the array?

May be some `regex` or some `jQuery` that we are not aware of?

All answers or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 341, accepted):

```
var arr = ["I", "am", "", "still", "here", "", "man"]
// arr = ["I", "am", "", "still", "here", "", "man"]
arr = arr.filter(Boolean)
// arr = ["I", "am", "still", "here", "man"]
```

[`filter` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

---

```
// arr = ["I", "am", "", "still", "here", "", "man"]
arr = arr.filter(v=>v!='');
// arr = ["I", "am", "still", "here", "man"]
```

[Arrow functions documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: I know exactly how you feel, I used it months ago, fixes so many small issues

Comment: @DiegoPlentz people who're still running IE8 are gonna have a lot more problems than just removing blanks in an array... I barely ever consider supporting that browser these days

Comment: This is the closest to `array.filter(!!)` that we can currently get :)

Comment: All credit for this answer should go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701319/javascript-regex-split-reject-null

Comment: Some explanation regarding `Boolean` would be nice.

Comment: @robsch The Boolean function is used as the test function, which converts values to booleans. Empty strings are considered falsy, while non-empty strings are truthy.

Answer (score 19):

```
var newArray = oldArray.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
```

Comment: Easily the best answer.  Does exactly what the question asks.  Doesn't remove zero values.

Answer (score 10):

**PLEASE NOTE:**
The documentation says:

> `filter` is a JavaScript extension to the ECMA-262 standard; as such
>   **it may not be present in other implementations of the standard**. You
>   can work around this by inserting the following code at the beginning
>   of your scripts, allowing use of filter in ECMA-262 implementations
>   which do not natively support it. This algorithm is exactly the one
>   specified in ECMA-262, 5th edition, assuming that fn.call evaluates to
>   the original value of Function.prototype.call, and that
>   Array.prototype.push has its original value.

So, to avoid some heartache, you may have to add this code to your script **At the beginning**.

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
  Array.prototype.filter = function (fn, context) {
    var i,
        value,
        result = [],
        length;
        if (!this || typeof fn !== 'function' || (fn instanceof RegExp)) {
          throw new TypeError();
        }
        length = this.length;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            value = this[i];
            if (fn.call(context, value, i, this)) {
              result.push(value);
            }
          }
        }
    return result;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = arr.filter(v => v);
```

as returned `v` is implicity converted to **truthy**

Answer (score 2):

If are using jQuery, [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) may be useful:

---

```
var arr = [ a, b, c, , e, f, , g, h ];

arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function(n){ return (n); });
```

`arr` is now `[ a, b, c, d, e, f, g];`

Comment: jquery seems like a lot of bulkiness for a menial task

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash's method, it works for string, number and boolean type

```
_.compact([0, 1, false, 2, '', 3]);
// => [1, 2, 3]
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#compact

Answer (score 0):

i.e we need to take multiple email addresses separated by comma, spaces or newline as below.

```
    var emails = EmailText.replace(","," ").replace("\n"," ").replace(" ","").split(" ");
    for(var i in emails)
        emails[i] = emails[i].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

    emails.filter(Boolean);
    console.log(emails);
```

Comment: `.replace(" ","").split(" ")` "replace all spaces with nothing, then try split at every space"