# Access JSONArrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to JavaScript. I have done similar requirements in Java using org.json library.

I have a String:

```
var string = "{\"id\" :[\"\"],\"State\" :[\"TX\",\"IA\"]}";
```

I am converting that string to a JSONObject using this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
```

I am trying to achieve this using JavaScript or jQuery. How do i get the JSONArrays inside this JSONObject. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Rayon. But i am trying to achieve this using javascript only. Do you still think i need to add java tag? Please let me know i will add if it helps.

Comment: I read it wrong. You have already achieved it using `JSON.parse`, what is left to be achieved ?

Comment: you just do `obj.id` and you've got the array. Or `obj.id.length` for the length of it (should be 1 here)

Comment: @Rayon I am trying to access the JSONArrays inside them.

Comment: Perfect this works . Thanks @Ivan

Comment: FYI, [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @Ivan but the length gives me 1 for obj.id.length. I dont know why. Any one please help me.

Comment: @user7637864 that's because your `id` array contains one item; an empty string

Comment: Can you please let me know how to get rid of that Empty String. I have tried (obj.id.isEmpty()) check . But its not working. @Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var jsonStr = "{\"id\" :[\"\"],\"State\" :[\"TX\",\"IA\"]}";
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

idArr=jsonObj.id;
stateArr=jsonObj.State;

idArr.forEach(function(id) {
    console.log(id);
});
stateArr.forEach(function(state) {
    console.log(state);
})
```

hope this will help you

Comment: but the idArr.length is giving me 1. That should not be the case right?

Comment: idArr is a String array and it contains one empty String in its 0th index, That is why  idArr.length is 1

Comment: Can you please let me know how to get rid of that Empty String. I have tried (obj.id.isEmpty()) check . But its not working. @Jackson Baby

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Use filter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888689/remove-empty-strings-from-array-while-keeping-record-without-loop/19888749#19888749

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with jquery 
Mention jquery as :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Code or script

```
var obj = $.parseJSON( '{\"id\" :[\"dddd\"],\"State\" :[\"TX\",\"IA\"]}' );
console.log(obj.id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @arjun.

Answer (score 0):

So once you have got the object, you have to get the array field on which you want to perform iteration. For Ex if you want to iterate over State, Check below:

---

```
for (var i=0;i<obj.State.length;i++)
                        {
                            obj.State[i] ;
                        }
```

Is this what you were looking for? If not, then pls be more clear.