# What does the .filter(i => i) do in this case?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, filter, cardano

I'm reading the process being built on

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/listening-for-payments-cli/#process-utxo-table

and I'm stuck on the results of this part:

```
// Calculate total lovelace of the UTXO(s) inside the wallet address
const utxoTableRows = rawUtxoTable.data.trim().split('\n');
let totalLovelaceRecv = 0;
let isPaymentComplete = false;

for (let x = 2; x < utxoTableRows.length; x++) {
    const cells = utxoTableRows[x].split(" ").filter(i => i);
    totalLovelaceRecv += parseInt(cells[2]);
}
```

I understand that up to the `.split(" ")` part, the table has been split into at least 2 items within the array of `utxoTableRows` since the first row the headers that we aren't interested in and the second row is the first `utxo` being processed. The `.split(" ")` then splits the row where there is a space but I don't know what the filter part does. The query `utxo` table looks as follows:

| TxHash | TxIx | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dfb99f8f103e56a856e04e087255dbaf402f3801acb71a6baf423a1054d3ccd5 | 0 | 1749651926 |

As you can see there are two rows. I'm completely lost at the filter component. I get more lost in the following command `parseInt(cells[2])`. I know somehow it takes the amount as a string and converts to integer. The [2] reference throws me off because wouldn't it have to be [3] since the amount is the 3rd item that gets split in that row? The only thing I can think of is that the `.filter(i => i)` throws out the `TxHash`, then saves the `TxIx` (in this case 0) in `cell[1]` and the amount (in this case 1749651926) in `cell[2]`, both as strings.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: This is why I prefer `.filter(Boolean)` or being very explicit (`.filter(i => i !== '')`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove empty array values ("") from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55685037/how-to-remove-empty-array-values-from-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

`filter` will filter out all items in the array where the callback returns `false` after coercion.

In this case, the `filter` removes all blank strings in the array. If the item is an empty string, the callback returns `false`, since empty strings, when coerced to a boolean, are `false` (see: [Falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)).